# Custom sorting x-axis in plotly heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I would like to custom sort the xaxis in my plotly heatmap but not sure how to go about doing this.

```
return {
    'data': [
        go.Heatmap(
            z=fights['win_rate'],
            y=fights['age_range'],
            x=fights['opp_age_range'],
            showscale=True)
    ],
```

I have tried creating a list with the order I would like and then using .loc to presumably apply this order to my column.

```
order = ['15-20','20-25','25-30','30-35','35-40','40-45','45-50']
return {
    'data': [
        go.Heatmap(
            z=fights['win_rate'],
            y=fights['age_range'],
            x=fights['opp_age_range'].set_index('opp_age_range']).loc[order],
            showscale=True)
    ],
```

However this does not change the order.

This is a sample of my data:

```
{'age_range': {0: '15-20', 1: '15-20', 2: '20-25', 3: '20-25', 4: '20-25'},
 'opp_age_range': {0: '25-30', 1: '25-30', 2: '20-25', 3: '20-25', 4: '20-25'},
 'division': {0: 'cruiser',
  1: 'super feather',
  2: 'feather',
  3: 'light',
  4: 'super bantam'},
 'sex': {0: 'male', 1: 'male', 2: 'male', 3: 'male', 4: 'male'},
 'wins': {0: 6, 1: 15, 2: 9, 3: 30, 4: 7},
 'loss': {0: 7, 1: 11, 2: 35, 3: 28, 4: 21},
 'draw': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 1, 4: 1},
 'other': {0: 1, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 2, 4: 2},
 'total_fights': {0: 16, 1: 29, 2: 47, 3: 61, 4: 31},
 'win_rate': {0: 37.5,
  1: 51.724137931034484,
  2: 19.148936170212767,
  3: 49.18032786885246,
  4: 22.58064516129032}}
```

So while I can sort the age_range and opp_range_columns easily. The problem is that when I convert this data to a heatmap, this is what I get:

[image]